# Why I don't have primary key in Azure Storage Account

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have this code in powershell:

```
$storageAccount = 'newstorage200'
$resourceGroup = 'Group'
$storeKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -StorageAccountName $storageAccount).Primary
```

The value stored in $storeKey variable is empty. Why I don't have a primary key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to cmdlet documentation here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607145.aspx, you should call it like this.

```
$storageAccount = 'newstorage200'
$resourceGroup = 'Group'
$storeKey = ((Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount)| Where-Object {$_.KeyName -eq 'key1'}).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

When I called it like this it succeded:

```
$storageAccount = 'newacc2001'
$resourceGroup = 'Group'
$storeKey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -StorageAccountName $storageAccount
$storeContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storeKey[0].Value
```